# Several tasks cancellation

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task, multitasking

There is one top task that launches another task.

```
var token = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
_task = new Task(() => WorkAction(this, token), token); //Top level task
```

The inner task implementation is:

```
public string FindDevice(IProgressViewModel progressViewModel, 
                         CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

        for (int i = 0; i < orderedComPortsList.Count; i++) {
            try {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
                return null;
            }
            string curPort = orderedComPortsList[i];
            if (InnerIsDeviceOnline(deviceModelId, curPort)) //The real long work
                return curPort;
            progressViewModel.CurrentValue = i;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

With this implementation the cancellation will occur only when the last InnerIsDeviceOnline is ended. How to implement FindDevice to make it cancellable immediately?

Update 1.

Can we do something like that:

```
 bool? result = null;
            Task<bool> parent = new Task<bool>(() => {
                bool? res = result;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                    while (res==null) {                           
                        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                    }
                }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

                result = InnerIsDeviceOnline(deviceModelId, comPort);
                return result.Value;
            }, cancellationToken);

            return parent;
```

The problem with it is that it never finishes (I don't know why). But this give us immediate cancellation.

Comment: So `WorkAction` is another task using the same `CancellationToken`?

Comment: If you need the task to finish *during* `InnerIsDeviceOnline` then you need to add cancellation support to that method.

Comment: Do you understand that by this way you just make the hole deeper? Sooner or later there will be the invokation which will take long time, and that invokation is beyond my control.

Comment: Do you understand that if you *don't* make the hole deeper you can't get the control you need? True cancellation support means the ability to stop at any point (gracefully), if `InnerIsDeviceOnline` is outwith your control then so is cancellation.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I'll update the post a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

In order to gracefully cancel long-running operations, your entire API needs to support cancellation at the specific granularity you need. In cases where the API for a long-running operation does not support `CancellationToken`, you'll need to provide an interfacing layer to provide that support. For example, the asynchronous `WebRequest.BeginGetResponse` does not support `CancellationToken`, but I was able to support it through this extension method, which calls [`Abort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.abort.aspx) in response to the `CancellationToken` getting canceled:

https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/blob/master/src/corelib/Core/WebRequestExtensions.cs

Comment: I took a look at your example. Ok, I'll rephrase my question. Is it possible to accomplish what I described if I change the signature of FindDevice and return from it Task<string>?

Comment: If `InnerIsDeviceOnline` takes longer than you want to wait for the cancellation, then you will need to add cancellation support to the implementation of that method. Otherwise, your API as a whole will not meet the granularity requirement I mentioned.

Comment: The problem is that InnerIsDeviceOnline consists of the single unmanaged function invokation. What could I do with that?